# Send alert to Account Owner

Tags: workflow, process-builder, administration, email-alert, alert

I have this requirement, How do I send an alert to the account owner if the last activity of any account is longer than 90 days ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Time-Depended](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1) workflow, or [scheduled actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US&type=0) in process builder to schedule some action in the future based on some condition.